# Strange error when moving tf.nn.dynamic_rnn to GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using to following setup:
Fedora 26, NVIDIA GTX 970, CUDA 8.0, CUDNN 6.0 and tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0 on python

My problem is that, when forcing a dynamic_rnn operator to run on my gpu using:

```
with tf.name_scope('encoder_both_rnn'),tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            _, encoder_state_final_forward = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.encoder_cell_forward,input_ph,dtype=tf.float32,time_major=False,sequence_length=sequence_length,scope='encoder_rnn_forward')
            _, encoder_state_final_reverse = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.encoder_cell_reverse,input_reverse,dtype=tf.float32,time_major=False,sequence_length=sequence_length,scope='encoder_rnn_reverse')
```

i receive the following error when calling the global variable initializer:

> InvalidArgumentError: Node 'init/NoOp': Unknown input node '^drawlog_vae_test.DrawlogVaeTest.queue_training/encoder/encoder/encoder_W_mean/Variable/Assign'

The variable is created using the following statement:

```
self.encoder_W_mean = u.weight_variable([self.intermediate_state_size * 2,self.intermediate_state_size*2],name='encoder_W_mean')
```

with

```
def weight_variable(shape,name=None,use_lambda_init=False):
with tf.name_scope(name):
    num_weights = float(reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,shape))
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=1) * math.sqrt(2.0/num_weights)
    if use_lambda_init:
        initial = lambda: np.random.normal(size=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial,dtype=tf.float32)
```

The strange thing about this is, the variable has nearly nothing to do with the both rnns. Is there any chance running my rnn on the GPU? Or is this just a strange error to tell me I can't run a rnn on a GPU?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. I suggest filing a Github issue with a minimal, self-contained reproduction.